# Images not showing in table in html

Tags: html, arrays, image, for-loop, html-table

```
function display()
{
    var menu_frame_filtered = top.menu_frame.filtered;
//filtered array taken from menu frame
    var displayed = menu_frame_filtered;
// giving filtered array new name
    var p = displayed.length;
//  window.open('Part_database/' + displayed[0] + '.jpg')
//displayed array contains image names and checked whether they are opening
//  
     document.write('<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">')
    document.write('<tr>')
    for(i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
    document.write('<td>' + displayed[i] + '</td>')
//image names in first cell
    }
    document.write('</tr>')
    document.write('<tr>')
    for(i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
    document.write('<td width="250" ><img src="Part_database/ '+ displayed[i] +' .JPG" alt=' + displayed[i] + ' width="200" height="200" /></td>')
//images in second cell
    }
    document.write('</tr>')
    document.write('</table>')
}
```

the above code is not displaying images in table...trying to figure out the challenge.
browser- IE8.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the size of the images are greater than 2000x2000. i wanted those to fit in cell of 200x200 size.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra space where it probably doesn't belong:

```
document.write('<td width="250" ><img src="Part_database/ '+ displayed[i] +' .JPG" alt=' + displayed[i] + ' width="200" height="200" /></td>')
                                                         ^                  ^
                                                         ^                  ^
                                                         ^                  ^
```

Comment: i was trying this since 1 week. anyways i donot mind much as it is my first code.. thanks a lot friend